# CQWP and PageFieldValue

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, mms

I am attempting to create a web part to use in a published page where it shows similar pages based on a metadata from the displayed page.

My field is call `News Topic`, terms are selected from MMS.  I have tried this in the Custom Value or Query `[PageFielValue:News Topic]`  When I try to save the webpart I get this error .......

```
Cannot save all of the property settings for this Web Part. There is a problem with one or more of the field values below.
```

and

`The column types do not match`

Any ideas how to fix?  Or am I missing something obvious here as it's looking at a term from the term store?